# Fortran 95 Missing expression error

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
300      do i=1,counter


open(1,file='Pcow_pd.txt')
write(1,*),Sw_pd(i), Pcow_pd(i)
open(2,file='Krw_pd.txt')
write(2,*),Sw_pd(i), Krw_pd(i)
open(3,file='Kro_pd.txt')
write(3,*),Sw_pd(i), Kro_pd(i)

print*, counter

end do   
print *,"filled =",filled
```

When I compile the code I get an error message at write lines which I cannot fix

> Compile error:  error 573 - Missing expression

Comment: It is just a typo, there shall be no comma after the `write(*,*)`. Voting to close as a simple typo. And I am sure the compiler printed more than you show, pleas always copy tye complete error message to your questions.

Comment: i do that, but when i run, just Sw_pd(i), Krw_pd(i) Outputs

Comment: you should open the files before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

As has been commented, there should be no comma before the list of items for output.  You should simply have

```
write(1,*) Sw_pd(i), Pcow_pd(i)
```

and so on.

The later line

```
print*, counter
```

where the comma before `counter` is absolutely necessary, may add a little confusion on writing.  This is perhaps increased by how `read` is used: there are two forms:

```
read *, x
read (*,*) y
```

The first example without an explicit statement of unit implies the same unit as the `*` in the second and it requires a comma.  The second must not have a comma.

A simple way to remember whether the output list has a comma first: if the format comes in isolation use the comma; if the unit is specified, don't.

Comment: yes , I do that and fixed error, but when i run Pcow_pd.txt and other txt file is empty.

Comment: @MaykPire  That is a different problem for a different question. Open a new question, show the complete code, the input files and all other details. Use different numbers for units. Not 1,2,3, but numbers larger than 10.

Comment: @MaykPire, as Vladimir F says, that's a different problem.  There isn't sufficient information here to diagnose the issue so you should work on a complete example (see [mcve]) and, if that doesn't help you, search for answers then ask another question.  One thing to check, though: have you `close`d the files before you look at the output (the program completing would do that)?